# Is there an interactive map of skiing resorts with snow forecasts?

Tags: united-states, skiing, weather, maps

I'm hoping to find a spot that gets snow in March, where the temperature doesn't get above freezing during the day.  I'd like to avoid the AM ice/PM slush conditions that occur in many places in the US.

I like to find an interactive map of skiing resorts in North American that combines these features:

- includes current snow depth (http://www.weather.gov/nerfc/snow)
- snowfall forecasts based on historical data that can be selected by a date range
- low and high temperatures
- includes all North American skiing resorts (https://www.onthesnow.com/united-states/map.html)
- based on google maps or openstreetmap

There are a lot of disparate sources, but I've not seen a unified source.  Is there one?

Comment: Plan a vacation based on averages is not very effective.  Lots of variance in mountain weather.

Comment: Not possible, you're always rolling the dice for skiing weather. Also this is a pure resource request and thus off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because off site resource request.

Comment: @whatsisname In that case, we would close an awful lot of other questions

Comment: I am voting to leave it open.  It is looking for a resource not directly avaialble in Outdoors.se.

Comment: @craig - keeping only those questions that match scope is one of the best ways to keep high quality content, in my opinion. We don't do product recommendations or list questions, so this is off topic here. It would also be possibly opinion based (my preferred skiing map may not be yours)

Comment: I think @whatsisname is right. This is seeking an outside resource based on another outside resource (googlemaps or openstreet map).  (The accepted answer to  [this meta post](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/), explains why this type of question would be off-topic.) I agree with Rory Alsop too about it being a list and possibly opinion-based. In addition, I think it's too broad based on the requested criteria. Craig, please don't think I'm criticizing you!  None of us are or would!

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is purely an off-site resource request, probably best served by google.